# Use HTTPS for requests on a specific port for PrizmDoc client

Tags: security, iis, https, reverse-proxy

I have a website running on HTTPS which uses Prizmdoc API. The website makes call to the Prizmdoc API using "http://:3000", where 3000 is the port used by Prizmdoc API to accept the calls.

Since my website is running on HTTPS, this call is deemed insecure by browser. And there is no way for me to select HTTPS in Prizmdoc as far as I know.

I need to change the Prizmdoc API address to "https://:3000" instead.

I tried checking firewall settings, but there is no option to allow HTTPS connections for a specific port. I tried reinstalling the Prizmdoc API client to see if it allows using HTTPS, but no luck.

I also thought about using IIS url rewrite, but prizmdoc API is not even hosted on IIS. So, I am unable to figure out how is that API accepting the requests over port 3000, and how can I allow HTTPS calls to that port.

Other option that I can try is to serve HTTP requests instead of HTTPS, but I am not sure if it is possible in C#.

Since both my website and Prizmdoc API are hosted on the same server, it should be possible for the website to make calls to a different port using SSL. But simply put, I am out of ideas to try.

TL;DR
Website and a third party API running on same server. Website makes call to the API using IP address and the port. Browser thinks it is a mixed content request and blocks the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this: set up a secure reverse proxy that listens for requests over HTTPS and then turns around and relays the requests to the port 3000. I have used this trick to secure an insecure API call. It should be good enough to pass the browsers' security checks as well.

Here are some IIS examples:

https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/